# How to use Archetype with Razor?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7, archetypes

I can't believe I couldn't find examples online.

This is my simple Archetype.
[image: My Archetype]

This is what I tried:

```
<img src="@CurrentPage.ctaTopLeft.image" alt="@CurrentPage.ctaTopLeft.text">
```

but it gives this error:

> 'Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel' does not contain a definition for 'image'

**EDIT:** This works:

```
<img src="@CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("ctaTopLeft").Fieldsets[0].GetValue("image")" alt="@CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("ctaTopLeft").Fieldsets[0].GetValue("text")">
```

Wondering if there is any shorter way of writing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no - an Archetype property can have a complex, nested set of data quite often in collections which may also be nested.  In fact, it's quite common to use a corresponding nested set of partial views just to render it out correctly if you have for example nested Archetype properties (it happens).

There are some tutorials/samples available for this sort of thing:

- http://imulus.github.io/Archetype/ - Archetype home on Github
- https://gist.github.com/kgiszewski/8863822 - this one is linked from the Archetype page above - gives some examples of usage with Razor/MVC.

There are also other packages designed to help you map Archetype properties to POCO as well - e.g. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/archetype-mapper/

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the typed way of getting the properties.

```
var property = Model.Contet.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("yourArchetypePropertyAlias");

if (property != null && property.Any()) {
    foreach (var item in property) {
        var imageId = item.GetValue<int>("yourImagePropertyAlias");
        var text = item.GetValue<string>("yourTextPropertyAlias");
    }
}
```

Comment: The typed way is my preferred starting point too; however you still need to iterate through and if you have nested archetype properties you'll most probably want to use some sort of hierarchical set of partial views.